# An error occurred while saving the URL rewrite Magento

Tags: error, url

I'm currently running Magento ver. 1.9.0.1
I would like to remove the .html prefix at the end of all url's on my site, but when I remove the .html from System > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimizations > Category URL Suffix and I try to reindex the "Catalog URL Rewrites", I got this error "An error occurred while saving the URL rewrite".
How can I fix this, so I can just remove the .html prefixes from my links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Bug in Magentos Url Category Suffix. The Suffix ist not added corectly in category urls. I think this error is causing your problem. I ask Magento for a patch and get it. May you can fix it on your own in the core until you have the patch. Check your sitemap, your categories should linked to url with a . at the end.